# Cannot test expected exception when using @Transactional with @Commit

Tags: java, spring, junit, transactions

I am using Spring Boot 1.4.0.M3.

I have an `@Entity` that has a `username` which should be unique:

```
@NotNull
@Column(unique = true)
@Pattern(regexp = "[a-zA-Z_\\-\\.0-9]+")
@Size(min = 1, max = 30)
private String username;
```

Using a Spring Data Repository, I want to test if there will be an exception when a duplicate username is used. This test works:

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class UserRepositoryIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repository;

    @Test(expected = DataIntegrityViolationException.class)
    public void test() {
        repository.save(User.createAdmin(repository.nextId(), "wim", "123456"));
        repository.save(User.createAdmin(repository.nextId(), "wim", "123456"));
    }
}
```

However, when adding `@Transactional` with `@Commit`, this test fails:

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@Transactional
public class UserRepositoryIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repository;

    @Test(expected = DataIntegrityViolationException.class)
    @Commit
    public void test() {
        repository.save(User.createAdmin(repository.nextId(), "wim", "123456"));
        repository.save(User.createAdmin(repository.nextId(), "wim", "123456"));
    }
}
```

But looking at the logging, the `DataIntegrityViolationException` is being thrown:

> 2016-05-24 09:05:16.619 ERROR 22790 --- [           main]
>   o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Unique index or primary key
>   violation: "UK_D8HGQ87BS4VPMC81NQ9G69G8X_INDEX_D ON
>   PUBLIC.MYPROJECT_USER(USERNAME) VALUES ('wim', 1)"; SQL statement:
>   insert into myproject_user (password, username, role, id) values (?,
>   ?, 'ADMIN', ?) [23505-191] 2016-05-24 09:05:16.620  INFO 22790 --- [
>   main] o.h.e.j.b.internal.AbstractBatchImpl     : HHH000010: On release
>   of batch it still contained JDBC statements 2016-05-24 09:05:16.629 
>   WARN 22790 --- [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager
>   : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener
>   [org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener@589b3632]
>   to process 'after' execution for test: method [public void
>   com.spring.boot.test.user.UserRepositoryIntegrationTest.test()],
>   instance
>   [com.spring.boot.test.user.UserRepositoryIntegrationTest@3ca278bc],
>   exception [java.lang.AssertionError: Expected exception:
>   org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException]

Why does the test fail? Could it be that JUnit checks if the exception is thrown before Spring commits the transaction?

Comment: Which is as expected... The exception will occur AFTER the transaction commit. The transaction commits AFTER the method ends. SO basically at the moment of checking there is no exception. You changed the behavior of the test with this. You need to commit inside your method.

Comment: "Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener" said it all. You want to commit but you want to assert that the commit fails. JUnit and Spring are not aware of each other so you can't use a JUnit assert for that stuff. As Martin said, use `TestTransaction#end` inside your test.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to that class. Did not know it existed. I have added an answer with the full working version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to commit. You just need to flush your *unit of work* to the database in order to see the `DataIntegrityViolationException`.

This is described in the note on "false positives" in the [Spring Reference Manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#testcontext-tx-false-positives). Note, however, that the `EntityManager` must be injected via `@PersistenceContext` (not `@Autowired`).

The following should work fine for you:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@Transactional
public class UserRepositoryIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository repository;

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    @Test(expected = DataIntegrityViolationException.class)
    public void test() {
        repository.save(User.createAdmin(repository.nextId(), "wim", "123456"));
        repository.save(User.createAdmin(repository.nextId(), "wim", "123456"));

        entityManager.flush();
    }
}
```

Regards,

Sam (*author of the Spring TestContext Framework*)

Answer (score 4):

Based on the comments by M.Deinum and Stephane Nicoll, this is the working version:

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@Transactional
public class UserRepositoryIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repository;

    @Test(expected = DataIntegrityViolationException.class)
    public void test() {
        repository.save(User.createAdmin(repository.nextId(), "wim", "123456"));
        repository.save(User.createAdmin(repository.nextId(), "wim", "123456"));

        TestTransaction.flagForCommit();
        TestTransaction.end();
    }
}
```

Note that both static methods need to be called to make it work.

Comment: Great you made my day, that's the perfect answer, short and sweet

Answer (score 3):

I need to test `DataIntegrityViolationException` in MVC controller test (`@WebAppConfiguration`) and do `@ResponseStatus` modification inside application by `@ControllerAdvice`.So yours approach doesn't suit for me, it flush too late. Unfortunately `@NotTransactional` annotation was excluded in Spring 4 , so I just separate my tests for `@Transactional` and not transactional. See also http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#integration-testing-annotations from

> @NotTransactional is deprecated

UPDATE. 2 ways solution:

- separate your test explicitly for Transactional and Non transactional
- use `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NEVER)` where transaction is not desirable

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. You could add this as a comment on the answer or ask a separate question referring to this question.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. But this is the good option for people with the same problem as yours.